# Combobox list with clickable button

Tags: extjs, extjs6-classic

I am trying to create a combobox with a dropdown with a clickable button.

I have overridden the `renderTpl` and copied the button instantiation code of the datepickers todayBtn. [This fiddle shows what I have now](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2j8e), the button is rendered but not yet clickable, the handler is not executed.

What am I missing?

Code:

```
Ext.define('EnhancedCombo', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
    xtype: 'enhancedcombo',
    footerButtonUI: 'default',
    selAllText: 'Select All',
    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;
        me.callParent(arguments);
        me.selAllBtn = new Ext.button.Button({
            ui: me.footerButtonUI,
            ownerCt: me,
            ownerLayout: me.getComponentLayout(),
            text: me.selAllText,
            tabIndex: -1,
            ariaRole: 'presentation',
            handler: me.selectAll,
            scope: me
        });
    },
    listConfig: {
        renderTpl: [
            '<div id="{id}-listWrap" data-ref="listWrap"',
                    ' class="{baseCls}-list-ct ', Ext.dom.Element.unselectableCls, '">',
                '<ul id="{id}-listEl" data-ref="listEl" class="', Ext.baseCSSPrefix, 'list-plain"',
                    '<tpl foreach="ariaAttributes"> {$}="{.}"</tpl>',
                '>',
                '</ul>',
            '</div>',
            '<div id="{id}-footerEl" data-ref="footerEl" role="presentation" class="{baseCls}-footer" style="">{%this.renderSelAllBtn(values, out)%}</div>',
            {
                disableFormats: true,
                renderSelAllBtn: function(values, out) {
                    Ext.DomHelper.generateMarkup(values.$comp.ownerCmp.selAllBtn.getRenderTree(), out);
                }
            }
        ],
    },

    selectAll: function() {
        console.log('select all');
        this.getPicker().getSelectionModel().selectAll();
    }
});
```

Comment: Not only handler but no listener is being fired for this button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every component has a method [`finishRender`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.Component.html#method-finishRender), which is called from the parent component during a render run. As I generate the markup manually through `generateMarkup`, I also have to call the `finishRender` method manually after the picker has been rendered before the button can be clicked.

In DatePicker, `finishRender` of the todayBtn is called from the overridden private [`finishRenderChildren`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/src/Date.js-3.html#line1469) method. Although I cannot override that private method of my picker, I can call the same `finishRender` method from an `afterrender` listener I can add to the picker (as Narendra Jadhav suggested):

```
listConfig: {
    ...
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function(picker) {
            picker.ownerCmp.selAllBtn.finishRender();
        }
    }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are using [`Ext.DomHelper.generateMarkup()`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/classic/Ext.dom.Helper.html) so it will return html in form of `Array`. So you are just appending the html of that button not component.

You could achieve this functionality, you need to use [`addListener`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/classic/Ext.Component.html#method-addListener) method on `picker` like this

```
picker.addListener('afterrender', function(){},scop);
```

And after that, inside of `afterrender` event you can add `click` event by getting dom element by using [`Ext.dom.Element.down()`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/classic/Ext.dom.Element.html#method-down) like this

```
picker.addListener('afterrender', (comp) => comp.el.down('.selectall').on('click', this.selectAll, comp), me)
```

## [FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/2j8n)

In above fiddle, I have created a demo.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        var btn = new Ext.button.Button({
            text: 'Working button',
            handler: function () {
                alert('Working button click');
            },
            listeners: {
                afterrender: function () {
                    console.log('afterrender Working button')
                }
            }
        });

        function getBtnHtml() {
            let button = new Ext.button.Button({
                text: 'No wokring button',
                handler: function () {
                    alert('Test 2');
                },
                listeners: {
                    afterrender: function () {
                        console.log('afterrender not Working button')
                    }
                }
            });
            return Ext.DomHelper.generateMarkup(button.getRenderTree(), []).join('')
        }

        Ext.create({
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'Demo',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            layout: 'hbox',
            defaults: {
                flex: 1,
                margin: 10
            },
            items: [btn, {
                xtype: 'panel',
                html: getBtnHtml()
            }]
        })

        Ext.define('EnhancedCombo', {
            extend: 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
            xtype: 'enhancedcombo',
            footerButtonUI: 'default',
            selAllText: 'Select All',
            multiSelect: true,
            initComponent: function () {
                this.callParent(arguments);

                var me = this,
                    picker = me.getPicker();

                me.selAllBtn = new Ext.button.Button({
                    ui: me.footerButtonUI,
                    ownerCt: me,
                    ownerLayout: picker.getComponentLayout(),
                    text: me.selAllText,
                    cls: 'selectall',
                    tabIndex: -1,
                    ariaRole: 'presentation',
                    scope: me
                });

                picker.addListener('afterrender', (comp) => comp.el.down('.selectall').on('click', this.selectAll, comp), me);

            },
            listConfig: {
                renderTpl: [
                    '<div id="{id}-listWrap" data-ref="listWrap"',
                    ' class="{baseCls}-list-ct ', Ext.dom.Element.unselectableCls, '">',
                    '<ul id="{id}-listEl" data-ref="listEl" class="', Ext.baseCSSPrefix, 'list-plain"',
                    '<tpl foreach="ariaAttributes"> {$}="{.}"</tpl>',
                    '>',
                    '</ul>',
                    '</div>',
                    '<div id="{id}-footerEl" data-ref="footerEl" role="presentation" class="{baseCls}-footer" style="">{%this.renderSelAllBtn(values, out)%}</div>', {
                        disableFormats: true,
                        renderSelAllBtn: function (values, out) {
                            Ext.DomHelper.generateMarkup(values.$comp.ownerCmp.selAllBtn.getRenderTree(), out);
                        }
                    }
                ],
            },

            selectAll: function () {
                console.log('select all');
                this.getSelectionModel().selectAll();
            }
        });

        Ext.create('EnhancedCombo', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            store: ['Test 1', 'Test 2']
        }).expand();

    }
});
```